# mysql Return duplicates and exclude lowest id

Tags: mysql

I am trying list all the rows from my query that will return all the duplicates next to each other so I can  then grab their id's but i also want to exclude the id with the lowest number from the results. How can I go about doing that with my query.

My Query

```
SELECT 
   a.tail_number,
   min(a.id),
   b.aircraft_id
from aircraft a
left join jobs b on a.id = b.aircraft_id
where
   a.active = 1 and b.aircraft_id is null
   group by a.tail_number having count(*) > 1
```

The current Output

```
tail_number min(a.id)   aircraft_id tail_count
125TH       4429        NULL        7
362FX       4223        NULL        7
439FL       4221        NULL        7
453FX       4220        NULL        7
455FX       4259        NULL        7
```

The output im trying to achieve

```
tail_number min(a.id)   aircraft_id tail_count
125TH       4429        NULL        1
125TH       4430        NULL        1
125TH       4431        NULL        1
125TH       4432        NULL        1
362FX       4223        NULL        1
362FX       4224        NULL        1
362FX       4225        NULL        1
362FX       4226        NULL        1
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Where is `tail_count` coming from? It's not in the query.

Comment: I don't understand your sample output. The query has `GROUP BY a.tail_number`. Why would you expect to get multiple rows with the same tail number if you're grouping by that column?

Comment: You said you wanted to exclude the lowest ID. But the lowest ID for `125TH` is `4429`, and your desired output includes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a subquery that gets the lowest ID for each tail number, and then exlude that from the results in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT a.tail_number, a.id
FROM aircraft AS a
JOIN (SELECT tail_number, MIN(id) AS minid
      FROM aircraft
      WHERE active = 1
      GROUP BY tail_number
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS m ON a.tail_number = m.tail_number AND a.id != m.minid
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j ON a.id = j.aircraft_id
WHERE j.aircraft_id IS NULL
ORDER BY a.tail_number, a.id
```

I've moved the checks for `active = 1` and `COUNT(*) > 1` into the subquery as well, since there's no longer any grouping in the main query.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. My only question is where are you getting b from if it isnt defined in the sql?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should be `m`.

Comment: This doesn't give the same result as in the output you said you're trying to achieve, it goes by your description. So it won't have `id = 4429` in the result because that's the lowest ID, and you said you want to exclude that.

Comment: And there's no `tail_count` because I have no idea where that's supposed to come from.

Comment: I left out `aircraft_id`, since it's always `NULL` because of the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Ahh ok i understand now, Thank you!